# How to import Repa

Tags: haskell, repa

I'm really new to the Haskell world, so please excuse me for the stupid question. I instlled Haskell Platform, I executed `cabal install repa` and then tried to load a file with this code in WinGHCi

```
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R
:m + Data.Array.Repa
```

but I get this:

```
Could not find module `Data.Array.Repa'
Perhaps you meant
  Data.Array.Base (from array-0.4.0.0)
  Data.Array.IO (from array-0.4.0.0)
  Data.Array.ST (from array-0.4.0.0)
```

Could someone please tell me how to remove the problem with not found module? Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list repa` say?

Comment: WARNING: cache is out of date: C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2012.4.0.0\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2012.4.0.0\lib\package.conf.d:

C:\Users\Faery\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386mingw32-7.4.2\package.conf.d:

This is what I get and after executing recache, I get the same.

Comment: You may be running an old version of ghc (in your path). Certainly, your system is broken somehow -- at a minimum run `ghc-pkg recache`

Comment: When I run it, I get the same result :( I downloaded Haskell Platform yesterday, I hope that it is up to date.

Comment: I can't even install repa, cabal tells me about some packages that are likely to be broken if I install it, and if I use --force-reinstall, the installation fails anyway. Are you sure it got even installed on your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the case, but did you, actually, look at the status message `cabal` returned when you attempted installing `repa`?

On my Windows system the latest (as of today, 2012.4.0.0) Haskell platform fails to install the latest (3.2.3.1) version of `repa`, e. g. `cabal install repa` doesn't work, saying that it would cause reinstalling of some system packages, thus possibly breaking the system. If I try installing anyway (with `cabal install repa --force-reinstalls`), it fails anyway, with an arcane status error message. If, by any chance, you didn't pay attention to the fact that the installation failed, and tried importing it anyway, I think the error message you get will be exactly what you had ("Could not find module...").

I was able, however, to install an earlier version of `repa`, namely `3.2.1.1`, with `cabal install repa-3.2.1.1`

I haven't tried using it yet, but at least importing and `:m + Data.Array.Repa` seems to work just fine.